# "Как дела?" and "как у тебя дела?" which one to use?

Tags: словоупотребление

In my book the meaning of **как дела?** is given as **how are you?**

Also the meaning of **как у тебя дела?** is given as **how are you?**

So which one should I use?

Comment: No much difference, the latter is just a bit more personal. Also keep in mind that in Russian both phrases are more about truly asking the question than in English, where "how are you?" is usually just a meaningless exchange of niceties.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"Как дела?" can be roughly translated as "How are things?"

"Как **у тебя** дела?" -> "How are things **with you**?"

So one is just a shorter version of the other.

There is also the polite version: "Как **у вас** дела?". For more background on the **тебя/вас** distinction, see [this question](https://russian.stackexchange.com/q/213/2104).

Answer (score 4):

'как дела?' is more like a polite way to start a conversation, compare to:

how are you doing? fine, and you? i'm ok.

'как у тебя дела?' shows more interest in the actual state of things of a person you have a conversation with. The difference is subtle, yet I think it exists.

Answer (score -1):

I believe "Как у тебя дела?" means "How are you doing?"

But "Как дела?" means "How are you"

It's a very small difference and I think most people only use "Как дела?" but it is good to know.